# Incrementing total hours using TimeOfDay

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I have the following code:

```dart
String total = "";
var format = DateFormat("HH:mm");
void increment() {
  setState(() {
    data = {
      'beginHour': result['beginHour'], // this gets the value "09:00" for example (String)
      'endHour': result['endHour'], // as well as this, for example: "11:00" (String)
      ...
      ...
    }
    var one = format.parse(result['beginHour']);
    var two = format.parse(result['endHour']);
    var delta = two.difference(one);

    total = delta.inHours.toString().padLeft(2, '0') + ":" + delta.inMinutes.remainder(60).toString().padLeft(2,'0'); // this returns the correct String, for example 02:00
```

Say this "total" String value is added to each card (to calculate the time of a work day for example), and I want the total of all cards (total of all "total"s). How can I do that?

Comment: Why don't you store `Duration`s objects (which can be easily added) instead of `String`s (which you then would need to parse back into `Duration`s)?

Answer (score 0):

You can store your total "work time" as a Duration object: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.19.3/dart-core/Duration-class.html:

```
var total = "";
var totalWorkTime = Duration();
final format = DateFormat("HH:mm");
void increment() {
(...)
```

Then you can add your `delta` duration to `totalWorkTime` duration, like this:

```
(...)
final delta = two.difference(one);
totalWorkTime += delta;
(...)
```

So after incrementing many times, your `totalWorkTime` duration should be sum of all deltas. Finally, you can print `totalWorkTime` in similar way to `delta`:

```
print(totalWorkTime.inHours.toString().padLeft(2, '0') + ":" + totalWorkTime.inMinutes.remainder(60).toString().padLeft(2,'0'));
```